# Connecting to Secondary SQL Server , if primary SQL Server is down

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have different Windows + Web applications which are connected to a SQL Server which is hosted in the web. I want to establish a secondary SQL Server to which applications can connect if the primary SQL Server goes down. I need a solution / help for two things:

1. Replicate the data to the secondary SQL Server should use mirroring? Or any other solution?
2. Should I create a heartbeat utility which will inform when the primary server is down?

Thanks

Comment: This is what always on availability groups are. You don't have to create a utility. It's easiest to set up straight in Azure

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Can i have any link

Comment: search 'mssql failover switch'/'sql server database mirroring failover'

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the SQL Server Version you are using and there are several options to provide high availability and disaster recovery for your databases.

First of all I would suggest defining your RPO (Recovery Point Objective) and RTO (Recovery Time Objective). In short you ask your business how much data you are allowed to loose and how much time it can take to get the database back online again. For a quick overview and a nice worksheet you can go to this [site](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/09/why-rpo-and-rto-are-actually-performance-metrics-too/).

The first responder kit on Brent's site includes a comprehensive overview of all HA/DR features to meet all RTO & RPO requirement and documentation [how to set up Availability Groups](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups/) (on premise and in the cloud).

That being said I would caution going down that road. It takes experience and time to set up and maintain a (especially automatic) fail-over solution for SQL Server. Availability Groups are based on Windows Server failover clustering. You will need to be comfortable setting up and supporting that as well. If your Servers will be in different subnets or not the same AD things get even trickier. In addition to that Availability Groups are an Enterprise Edition feature that comes with a hefty price tag. Basic Availabilty Groups are supported with SQL Server 2016 on Standard Edition ([guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5187/deploying-sql-server-2016-basic-availability-groups-without-active-directory-part-1-building-the-platform/)).

If your SQL Server is already in the cloud I would take a look at Azure SQL DB. You can have a lot of features with minimal administrative effort. Microsoft has nice guides to get you started:

[Failover groups and active geo-replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview)

[Designing highly available services using Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery)

To answer your questions about mirroring:
You can start here for a step by step [guide](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-citation-sql-blog-by-hemantgiri-s-goswami-sql-mvp/2016/03/25/configure-sql-server-database-mirroring-step-by-step/).

You do not need a heartbeat application. Mirroring will take care of that. To enable your application to connect to the mirror db you can add the mirror to the connection string of your application. See [Clarification on the Failover Partner in the connectionstring in Database Mirror setup.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup/)

Comment: Thanks alot , a very detailed answer, I am using SQL Server 2016 Std Edition and thinking  to migrate for Cloud

Comment: Happy to help. In that case I would suggest looking into Azure SQL DB with replication and if the cloud is not an option Basic Availability Groups.